# Can't delete file after drag drop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm moving a picture from explore to a win form. That works fine. After i have moved the picture i want to delete it in the folder, but that don't work. I'm getting the error that the file is in use in the winform.

I have tried with:

```
File.Delete(files[0])
files = null
img = null
img.Dispose()
```

But I still can't delete or move the file.

```
private void frmADManager_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int x = PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).X;

            int y = PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)).Y;

            if (x >= pbUser.Location.X && x <= pbUser.Location.X + pbUser.Width && y >= pbUser.Location.Y && y <= pbUser.Location.Y + pbUser.Height)

            {

                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                Image img = Image.FromFile(files[0]);
                if (img.Width == 648)
                { 
                    pbUser.Image = img;
                    SavePicture = true;
                    tsbtnSave.Enabled = true;
                    toolStrip1.Focus();
                    File.Delete(files[0]);
                    files = null;
                    img = null;
                    img.Dispose();                        
                }
                else
```

Comment: If you need to retain image in `pbUser` then you should use a copy of the source.  I.E.: `pbUser.Image = new Bitmap(img);`.  Also follow the answer from @waka.  Do not attempt to use `img.Clone()` as the clone will also reference the source file and prevent you from deleting the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to delete the image before you call `img.Dispose()`. Until the img is disposed it is still "in use", so just change the lines around:

```
if (img.Width == 648)
{ 
    pbUser.Image = img;
    SavePicture = true;
    tsbtnSave.Enabled = true;
    toolStrip1.Focus();
    img.Dispose();//you are disposing the img, no need to null it
    File.Delete(files[0]);
 }
```

Comment: If I only use Wakas answer, I get the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll" If I also use the answare from TnTinMn I get error when comitting the change "System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: A constraint violation occurred."

Comment: Ok, I moved the img.Dispose() till after I had committed the changes. That worked. Thanks to both of you, for your help.